# Can I have a wizard on a tablet?

Tags: navigation, tablet, wizard

I'm designing this long process to be completed on a tablet interface.
For simplicity, I want to break the process into several steps, and allow next/previous navigation. Since it would take around 4 or 5 steps, I consider adding a "train" showing the process and the current step.

Is this the right way to go when designing for a tablet?
Any examples for anything similar?

Comment: I suppose the question you could ask yourself is *why wouldn't this work on a tablet*? To which I can't think of any reason as to why a tablet would effect the flow.

Comment: One issue I can think of - connectivity. A tablet is wifi or even 3G so there's no guarantee that the connection will still be there when you start screen 1 and then move on to screen 2. You should plan for situations when connectivity goes down part-way through the process.

Comment: @JonW I don't read any information on if this process needs the internet at all. For all we know, it is a stand-alone app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implementing a wizard, or a stepped process should be no problem for tablets. Apps use this often in **walkthroughs**, and also **registration/sign up** processes, **purchases** and **content creation**.

## Walkthroughs

[image: Walkthrough on the iPad app, Cook]
These are essentially slides describing your app's functionality with a progress tracker to know what step you're on. Often accompanied with animations.
You could find more at http://pttrns.com/ipad/categories/16-walkthroughs

## Purchase

These typically divide the process into steps such as selection, shipping details, payment details, payment, confirmation.

As for your question, **using wizards in tablet applications is perfectly fine**.

Answer (score 8):

I would say a wizard 'stepped' process, with a progress tracker, is perfectly viable on a tablet. The full screen format should lend itself nicely to tapping through a form.

Some related points to bear in mind

- keep amount of steps relatively low but…
- don't make each step too long
- clearly indicate on the progress tracker which step the user is on
- allow 'next' and 'previous' options where possible (with clear error/alert indication if the user is trying to go forward or back with fields not complete)

some more points here:

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/01/15/progress-trackers-in-web-design-examples-and-best-design-practices/